# Listing directory as different user via ssh on remote solaris machine

Tags: unix, ssh, solaris, remote-access

I'm trying to list the directory on remote solaris machine as a different user, but I always get the list of homedirectory of the user. I'm using

sudo ssh remoteip su - username -c 'ls -al /var/adm'

as a result I see the content of username's home directory

I also tried

sudo ssh username@remoteip 'ls -al /var/adm'

but this doesn't work either (password is asked )as it looks like I only can do ssh with sudo and then change user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ssh host 'sudo -u username sh " id; ls -l /var/adm"'
```

If you really need to sudo to run ssh then add sudo to the start of the line. 
hth.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, it keeps asking the password. I'm only able to ssh as sudo. However coincidentially you helped me anyway, as I used doublequotes and qutoes to separate ssh from su -c as you similarily did in your example. So, sudo ssh remoteip " su - username -c ' command ' " did work for me. Thank you very much